# Laravel's dynamic carousel isn't working properly; it's only showing one picture

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I try to create a dynamic carousel in Laravel, but all I see is one image. Despite my efforts to find a solution, none of them appear to be working. Please Help!!!

This is my index blade.

```
 @section('content')
<div class="container-fluid p-0 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
  <div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">   
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach($sliders as $key => $slider)
         <div class="carousel-item {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
             <img class="w-100" src="{{asset($slider->image) }}" alt="Image">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <div class="container">
                     <div class="row justify-content-center">
                         <div class="col-lg-8">
                             <h1 class="display-1 text-white mb-5 animated slideInLeft">{!! $slider->title !!}</h1>

                             @if ($slider->subtitle)
                             <h3 class="display-5 text-white mb-5 animated slideInDown">{!! $slider->subtitle !!}</h3>
                             @endif

                             @if ($slider->description)
                             <h4 class="display-8 text-white mb-5 animated slideInDown">{!! $slider->description !!}</h4>
                             @endif

                             @if ($slider->button_link)
                             <a href="{{asset($slider->button_link) }}" class="btn btn-primary py-sm-6 px-sm-8">Read More</a>
                             @endif
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

     </div>
 @endforeach

     <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
         data-bs-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
     </button>
     <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
         data-bs-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
       </button>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my controller.

```
function index() : View {
    $sliders = Slider::where('status', 1)->get();

     return view('layout.frontend_layout.index',compact('sliders'));
 }
```

Comment: What is the content of `$sliders`? if there is only one item in it this is correct. Try doing `dd($sliders)` after retrieving it to check.

Comment: i see 3 array when i do dd($sliders).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You placed the `@endforeach` in the wrong location, move it to after the closing tag of the `carousel-item`, it's located one too far away right now.